# How to align image right next to <h2>

Tags: html, css

So I have a question that might be easy but I could not find anything that works after a lot of searches.

I have this h2 tag which is defined in .aspx. Right below this, I have a div with an id.

```
 <h2>Documents</h2>
  <div id="abcdocuments"></div>
```

I am appending an image before the start of the whole grid which gives me a result like this that there is a heading first. then below I get that image and then below the whole grid

I want the image to be right next to Documents Heading and for some reason, I can't define the img at .aspx It has to be at the class level. Also, I can not move my heading at the class level. Is there any way I can change the styling or something to move the image next to the header?

my html:

```html
  <h2>Documents</h2>
 <div><img  src="../../Images/pincomment.png" 
  style='width:2%;cursor:pointer;' 
      /></div>
```

Comment: given the resulting HTML and CSS it'd be easier to help; there are many ways, starting from giving the image (possibly inside an extra DOM container to apply the styling) a negative margin-top. The H2 need not be a display:block element. More than one way to skin a cat!

Comment: @flowtron I have given the html and the only styling I have done to the image is defined in the tag. There is no other css that is done

Comment: *resulting* html, not the steps you say you're doing .. you're expecting a lot of guess and leg work (rather finger work) from people that /want/ to help you.

Comment: @flowtron I have added my html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: It looks as though the img is a small sort of 'icon' to go next to the heading rather than a big image with meaning in its own right. If so, maybe adding it as a pseudo element or even a background to h2 would give you what you want, and the correct semantics?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes its a small icon on which I have to add some onclick functionality. Can you maybe edit my html ?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As it has functionality then pseudo element won't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum…</h2>
<div style="position:relative;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNk+A8AAQUBAScY42YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:2%;top:-3em;left:17em;position:absolute;"/></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the heading and the image sit next to each other by making them inline-block.

This snippet is simple because the given HTML is not in its real life context - so the specificity in the CSS does not need added classes, but in the real situation you would of course need to ensure that you had selected the right h2.

```css
h2,
h2+div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Documents</h2>
<div>
  <img src="../../Images/pincomment.png" style='width:2%;cursor:pointer;' /></div>
<div class="FDAccordions"></div>
```